# Why wont my row highlight? - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to highlight a row in Angular.  Here is my html:

```
<tr  ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}" ng-repeat="encounter in encounters | filter:search" data-id="{{encounter.id}}" ng-click="getSelectedRow($index)">
```

Here is the directive that for the row.  It has the click handler `getSelectedRow()`

```
angular.module('app').directive('encounterItemTable', function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/encounter.item.table.html',
    scope: {
      encounters : '='
    },

    link: function(scope) {
      scope.getSelectedRow = function(index) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('selectedRow', { rowIndex: index });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

This get broadcast to the controller to highlight the row.  Here is where the controller should do it's magic:

```
  $scope.$on('selectedRow', function(event, data) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = data.rowIndex;
    $scope.selectedEncounter = $scope.encounters[data.rowIndex];
  });
```

The code in the controller gets hit, but the row never gets highlighted.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you create a plunker with the example please?

Answer (score 2):

ng-class="{selected: $index==$parent.selectedIndex}"

$parent being the key, else you are pointing to the selectedindex on the row, not the scope

Comment: "selectedindex on the row" --- what does it mean?

Comment: Jason could you explain that in more detail? btw - this didnt fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends who holds the member property `selectedIndex` - if it's the directive, then you shouldn't need $parent, b/c the ng-repeat can see the directive's scope.  However, if it's the page controller (or a controller that is housing the directive), then, you need to access it via the directive's $parent.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HWbe/9/

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">enter a number from 0 - 9
    <input ng-model='selectedIndex' type='text'>

    Uses appliction scope
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='x in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]' ng-class='{"selected": $index==selectedIndex}'>{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
        <my-directive></my-directive>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<div><hr/>Uses $parent.scope<ul><li ng-repeat='y in [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 10]' ng-class='{\"selected\": $index==$parent.selectedIndex}'>{{y}}</li></ul></div>"
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {}
```